# Android - saving Int on Internal Storage error

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

I am trying to save an int (`score`) on the Internal storage of a real device, and for some reason, when I load it, it makes `score` equals to 0. 
Code:

```
public int score;

String scoreString = Integer.toString(score);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
final TextView best = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.best);

// Save
            try {
                file = getFilesDir();
                fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("record.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fileOutputStream.write(scoreString.getBytes());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save() works fine " + scoreString + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 // load
            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("record.txt");
                int read = -1;
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                while ((read = fileInputStream.read()) != -1){
                    buffer.append((char)read);
                }
                Log.i("ELY", buffer.toString());
                String record = buffer.substring(0);
                best.setText("Best: " + record);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Load() OK " + record , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fileInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        fileInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can somebody help me?
 Thanks

Comment: Why not use a `SharedPreference`?

Comment: You code is working file, check it again there must be something else causing that issue.

Comment: I know there is nothing wrong, because I use "score" before saving and loading it and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** Well If you just want to save score you can use **SharedPrefernces**

To get Score:

```
 public int getScore() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getInt("SCORE", 0);
}
```

To store Score:

```
public void setScore(int score) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("SCORE", score);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: how do I load it later?

Comment: See when the first time you will call getScore() it will return 0 because that has not been set yet after when you will call setScore(int score) after user has scored it will be save so the next time when you will call getScore() It will result in previous score not 0

Comment: when I put this in my code it says "cannot resolve symbol 'context'

Comment: context is a variable which I have declared sorry use getApplicationContext() instead of context or create a Gloabl variable private Context context; and in onCreate() function declare it like context=getApplicationContext();